# Confusion with pouch-transform encryption and replication

Tags: encryption, couchdb, pouchdb

My goal is to assure that all data in remote couch db will be encrypted. When I follow this example from pouch-transform docs, my data is not encrypted on remote end point after sync,

```
pouch.transform({
      incoming: function (doc) {
        encrypt(doc);
      },
      outgoing: function (doc) {
        decrypt(doc);
      }
    });
```

when I encrypt in outgoing it does, but in this case my data encrypted locally as well. What I'm doing wrong here, isn't the point of encryption to have data encrypted in remote db? So the only way to achieve this will be to create set/get wrappers and encrypt in them? Can I detect somehow document destination in outgoing call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> isn't the point of encryption to have data encrypted in remote db?

No. As explained in the [package description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/transform-pouch):

> Apply a transform function to documents before and after they are stored in the database.

In other words, it only modifies the data at rest.

This plugin has exactly no effect on the data being sent to/from CouchDB--only in the way the data is stored within PouchDB itself.

If you want to encrypt documents in CouchDB, too, you need to do this at the application layer.  That is, encrypt the data yourself, and store it in the document or as an attachment in encrypted form.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I've got the problem too. I do not wanna transform the data when replicating, so I've hacked in and added a `replicating` flag to pass through wrappered functions when replication: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/pull/7774

And modified the `pouch-transform` pacakge to pass the option to the `outcoming` callback:

```
{
  // decrypt it here.
  outgoing: async (doc, args: IPouchDBWrapperArgs, type: TransformPouchType) => {
    const {options} = args;
    if (!options.replicating) {
      doc = await this.decryptDoc(doc, options);
    }
    return doc;
  },
};
```